# How to calculate number of days by subtracting date_time field from current date_time?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have reservations table to store hotel reservations, this table has reservation_id, customer_id, rommno, and checking date also there is another optional field, checkout field which will use when person checked out and also the status field will updated to checkout status wile firstly putted checking status.

i need a query to find number of stayed dates from the checking date.
needed result will look like this:

customer_id, roomno, checkin_date, due_nights

due nights will be result of subtraction of checkin_date and current date, i tried this sql query and it returns #Error

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(reservations.due_nights,  now(), reservations.checkin_date) from reservations
```

my table view is link below

[current table view click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LiNRzY7JjvejVjS29URlJfNFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your query is in SQL Server or in Access ?

Comment: It should be datediff(day, reservations.checkin_date, isnull(reservations.checkout_date, getdate())?

Comment: Is the table view in the link the wanted result? or is it what you have now?

Comment: table view is the table i have now,  the result i need i mentioned inside my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query is wrong

**SQL SERVER**
the syntax for datediff is

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

Also the function for getting current date in sql server is `getdate()` not `now()`

so in your case it will be

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY,reservations.checkin_date, getdate())
```

eg:-

```
select DATEDIFF(Day,'06-07-2015 14:00:00',GETDATE())
     will return 10
```

**MS-ACCESS**

```
DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])

 DATEDIFF("d",reservations.checkin_date,Now())

  where d represents the interval as day

eg: -  DateDiff ("d", #15/10/2003#, #22/11/2003#)

       result will be 38
```

Comment: Am using MS Access Database, MSAccess uses now(), when i execute it ask me to input DAY. @Sachu

Comment: @saedawke remove the sql-server tag from your question then

Comment: @ Sachu removed brother

Comment: @Sachu Need complete query, how to write this query

Comment: @saedawke  try `SELECT DATEDIFF("d", reservations.checkin_date, now() ) from reservations`

Comment: woow it works well, but where is the customer_id also i need customer_id in the result

Comment: @saedawke put customer_id also in select statement like `Select customer_id,DATEDIFF(...`